# Qt cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'TCHAR*'

Tags: qt, wchar-t, tchar

I transfer the project from visual studio to QT and when the project build - displayed errors. How to fix them without making significant changes in the code?.

```
cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'TCHAR*'
cannot convert '_TCHAR*' to 'const wchar_t*'
cannot convert 'const wchar_t [15]' to 'TCHAR*'
cannot convert 'TCHAR*' to 'const wchar_t*'
...
```

Several dozen such errors.

PS It is strange that Google does not have any useful results on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

does your new build know about `TCHAR*` ?  it is a windows specific 'feature'

Comment: Yes. tchar.h  typedef char TCHAR;

Comment: I would use Qt string class where ever you can and convert to from the native type when you need to call an external api. TCHAR is almost always a bad idea - even just on windows.

Comment: A lot of errors. I need a simple solution. I can't use QT classes, because the application becomes dependent on the QT librarys